# FastVectorHighlighter phrase highlighting not working with stemming

Tags: java, solr, lucene, stemming, fast-vector-highlighter

Attempting to write a stemmer in  storing both the stem and the original word have caused some problems with getting phrases to highlight using the `FastVectorHighlighter`.

The input string is `foo bar baz` with `ba` being the stem of `bar`. Below image illustrates the analysis

[image]

A phrase search yields a match but no highlight at all

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/select
   ?q="foo bar baz"
   &qf=text
   &hl.requireFieldMatch=true
   &hl.fl=text
   &hl.usePhraseHighlighter=true
   &hl.boundaryScanner=breakIterator
   &hl.useFastVectorHighlighter=true
   &hl=true
   &defType=edismax
```

Where `hl.bs.type=WORD` is used by the `boundayScanner`.

Both approaches, `hl.useFastVectorHighlighter=false` and quotes from the query, results in highlighting for all terms.

`Solr 3.6.2` is being used, and the field is defined below

```
<field name="text" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" 
     multiValued="true" termVectors="true" 
     termPositions="true" termOffsets="true"/>
```

And analyzed as

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="my.custom.StemmerFactory" preserveOriginal="true"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out `hl.fragSize` wasn't set to a large enough value to include the entire highlighted sequence. The silly problems are often the worst.